# How do I pass additional arguments to an event callback?

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to pass additional arguments to an event callback?

For example, if my event binding looked like this;

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.do_something, self.button)
```

How could I pass the arguments to my method?

```
self.do_something(self,event,arguments):
    """do something with arguments"""
    pass
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass arguments into event bindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173687/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-into-event-bindings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lambda:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event, args=args: self.do_something(event, args), self.button) 

self.do_something(self,event,arguments):
    """do something with arguments"""
    pass
```

Comment: lambda can mess you up if you use it in a for loop. I prefer the functools.partial approach.

Comment: @FogleBird, the mess can happen if you write `lambda event: self.do_something(event, args)` instead of `lambda event, args=args: self.do_something(event, args)` (note `args=args`)

Answer (score 9):

Use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial), or in the general case a [`lambda` expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

The partial form would be

```
functools.partial(self.do_something, args)
```

Note that in this case the `event` argument will be passed at the end of the argument list.  The equivalent lambda form is:

```
lambda event: self.do_something(args, event)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear when you want to provide these arguments, but if you want to provide them at `Bind` time (such that you can have a `do_something` which supports multiple uses), you can use `functools.partial`:

```
def do_something(self, arg, event):
  pass

self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, functools.partial(self.do_something, arg), self.button)
```

Then when `do_something` is called, it will be called with the `arg` you passed in to `partial`, as well as the event passed by the callback.

Comment: I forgot about doing it that way. I just use lambda myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda function. There's some documentation on this on the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks). I also wrote about it in my [lambda tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/19/the-python-lambda/). Here's the lame example I created when I wrote that (which is in the article too):

```
import wx

########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "wx lambda tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        button8 = wx.Button(panel, label="8")
        button8.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button8.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))
        button10 = wx.Button(panel, label="10")
        button10.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name=button10.GetLabel(): self.onButton(evt, name))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(button8, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(button10, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event, buttonLabel):
        """"""
        print "You pressed the %s button!" % buttonLabel

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```