# wxpython, passing data to a function in self.Bind

Tags: wxpython

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this to know if its possible. Ive looked in the wxpython demo and done some googling to no avail.

how do I pass some sort of data to the function call when I am binding actions?

for example

self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DoThis, item1)

self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DoThis, item2)

I have a set of menu options that I want to be handled by the same function (DoThis), but need to pass that function some data because its output depends on which menu item was selected.

I know I can just bind each menu item to a different function so could just replicate it a bunch of times, but for the sake of clarity and length of code, it would be much simpler to handle it all in the same function, because I have about a dozen menu items. Is this even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a related question is [Is it possible to pass arguments into event bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173687/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-into-event-bindings). This can do it by passing arguments to callback, as you can see to [passing arguments to callbacks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks).

Comment: That is perfect! I need to learn the terminology better so its easier to find the answers via search, thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this.

```
import wx


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        menuFile = wx.Menu()
        self.menuSave = menuFile.Append(-1, 'Save', 'Save Document')
        self.menuClose = menuFile.Append(-1, 'Close', 'Close Application')
        menubar.Append(menuFile, '&File')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onMenu)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        pSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        panel.SetSizer(pSizer)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(vSizer)
        self.Layout()

    def onMenu(self, event):
        menuId = event.Id
        if menuId == self.menuSave.Id:
            print 'menuSave'
        elif menuId == self.menuClose.Id:
            print 'menuClose'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wxapp = wx.App(False)
    testFrame = TestFrame(None)
    testFrame.Show()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried. It works!

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lamdba evt, a=1, b=2: self.funcName(evt, a, b), buttonName)
```

So, you can pass any data to any function.