# How can I store values of buttons in variables? (Python Gtk)

Tags: python, gtk

I need to store the value of a button that was clicked into a variable. So I need to connect the button with the variable how can I do that? Here are my variables:

```
    self.first_num = 0
    self.second_num = 0
    self.result = 0
    self.operation = ""
```

And then I need to use them in this function e.g. in an addition:

```
    def equal_clicked(self, result):
    if self.operation == "plus":
        self.result = self.first_num + self.second_num
        self.entry.set_text(self.result)

    def button2_clicked(self, button2):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(2))
```

I hope this is enough code to show you my problem and i would appreciate an answer.

```
    button5 = Gtk.Button(label="5")
    button5.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked)
    vbox.pack_start(button5, True, True, 0)
    vbox.pack_end(button5, True, True, 0)
    self.add(button5)
```

Comment: I assume you're making something like a calculator? I'm not sure what you mean by the value of a button as buttons can't hold values, but if you mean use the number from each number button, just set up a callback function that connects to the `clicked` signal, then initialize your variables with a static number hardcoded into each callback.

Comment: So i added the function for the button with the number of "2". Do i have to initialize the variables in that function? Or am I assuming wrong? And btw yes I am working on a calculator.

Comment: that would work. You could also use your original plan and just set `self.first_num` to two when that button is clicked. The answer looks like it should work though. I don't use Python so I don't have experience in Python lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make GUI applications for work a lot. The main idea is to bind a single function to each button, but pass in a different variable with each button.

Here is a full example for Python Gtk:

```
import pygtk
import gtk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        #Setup window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_border_width(10)
        self.boxSizer = gtk.HBox(False, 0)

        #Create widgets
        self.button1     = gtk.Button("1")
        self.button2     = gtk.Button("2")
        self.button3     = gtk.Button("3")
        self.buttonPlus  = gtk.Button("+")
        self.buttonEqual = gtk.Button("=")
        self.entry       = gtk.Entry(max=0)

        #Bind Events to a single function
        #You would do this for every button. 
        #The first parameter in the connect() function is the name, 
        #the second is the function you are binding, 
        #and the third is the argument we are passing into the function.
        self.button1.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked, 1)
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked, 2)
        self.button3.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked, 3)
        self.buttonPlus.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked, "+")
        self.buttonEqual.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked, "=")

        #Build Window
        self.window.add(self.boxSizer)
        self.boxSizer.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
        self.boxSizer.pack_start(self.button2, True, True, 0)
        self.boxSizer.pack_start(self.button3, True, True, 0)
        self.boxSizer.pack_start(self.buttonPlus, True, True, 0)
        self.boxSizer.pack_start(self.buttonEqual, True, True, 0)
        self.boxSizer.pack_start(self.entry, True, True, 0)

        #Show objects
        self.button1.show()
        self.button2.show()
        self.button3.show()
        self.buttonPlus.show()
        self.buttonEqual.show()
        self.entry.show()
        self.boxSizer.show()
        self.window.show()

    def button_clicked(self, widget, value):
        """Your first function and second function could be combined like this.
        What this would do is have a single function that is bound to each button. 
        The arguments passed into it would be different for each button.

        Despite using the 'evil eval' function, I figure this is the route you are going.

        This removes the need to (1) have a different function for each button, 
        and (2) you do not need to store values in variables like this:
            self.first_num = 0
            self.second_num = 0
            self.operation = ""

        Your code will be cleaner and easier to modify for future projects.
        """
        if (value != None):
            if (value != "="):
                #Add something to the text
                self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(value))
            else:
                #Evaluate the text
                self.result = eval(self.entry.get_text())
                self.entry.set_text(str(self.result))
        else:
            #Clear the text
            self.entry.set_text("")

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example = Example()
    example.main()
```

---

This concept should work for *any* GUI creation package. Some packages may take a bit more work than others, though. 
For example, wxPython does not let you pass arguments into functions. You can get around this limitation by doing what "Florian Bosch" says on [Is it possible to pass arguments into event bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173687/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-into-event-bindings).
(Note: This method should work for any GUI package that does not allow you to pass arguments into bound functions)

For, wxPython: Bind all of your buttons like this:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "1"), button1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "2"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "3"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "4"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "5"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "6"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "7"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "8"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "9"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "0"), button2)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "+"), buttonAdd)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "-"), buttonSubtract)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "*"), buttonMultiply)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "/"), buttonDivide)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, "="), buttonEqual)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: button_clicked(event, None), buttonClear)
```

(Use this part: `lambda event: button_clicked(event, "1")` in place of where you would normally connect a button to a function.)

---

The idea here, regardless of the GUI module used, is to bind a single function 
to all of your calculator's buttons and just pass in a different value for each button.

Comment: So I added the defintion of one button to my question. Is this the right way to go? And I do not understand how or where I define the value in the button_clicked function? And btw thanks for the answer.

Comment: I did a bit of research into Python Gtk. Looks like it is easier to bind functions than it is for wxPython. I added some more information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I tried using the code and I changed some things around but it does not work. For me this is the solution I just need to change something. Have you tried the code?

Comment: I have changed my code a bit you can see it above. Thats how I binded my buttons previously.

Comment: I downloaded Python Gtk and created a working simple example for you. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much you helped me al lot.